# How do I configure proxy settings for LOCAL SYSTEM?

Tags: windows, proxy, windows-service, windows-registry, local-system

If I edit Proxy Settings through the Control Panel, the settings are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ProxyEnable` and `...\ProxyServer`. These settings are of course not used when running as a service under `LOCAL SYSTEM`.

So I tried setting `ProxyEnable` and `ProxyServer` under `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\...` (as well as `HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\...` and all the other users on the system), but that does not work.

How do I set the proxy settings for the `LOCAL SYSTEM` user?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is actually the value in `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings` that is used.

Since that is not easily modified, you can modify the proxy settings for a user, export the registry key, modify the path in the exported file to `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18` and reimport it.

Comment: This solved my problem, many thanks! I ended up writing a Java class to manipulate the DefaultConnectionSettings hex string, as I needed to set the proxy programmatically.

Comment: Can this work if authentication is required?

Comment: I had to use another ID than `S-1-5-18` and I retrieved it by issuing: `wmic useraccount get name,sid|findstr some-user-name`.

Answer (score 14):

First, run `cmd` as administrator to open a command prompt.

Command to copy proxy settings of current user to WinHttp:

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie
```

To reset the proxy to default settings:

```
netsh winhttp reset proxy
```

To show proxy settings of current user:

```
netsh winhttp show proxy
```

Comment: [One liner](https://superuser.com/questions/489527/how-can-i-configure-proxy-settings-for-all-apps-system-ie-etc): `netsh winhttp import proxy source =ie`

Comment: this doesn't work running as a `SYSTEM` it will return none

Answer (score 7):

Another way, albeit much messier, is to use [psexec to open a command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151184/interactive-command-prompt-as-network-service) running as LOCAL SYSTEM, then from that open iexplore.exe, modify the settings appropriately.

Comment: `PsExec.exe -i -s regedit /s "%~dp0Internet Settings.reg" `

Answer (score 5):

The Same thing can be done much easier in this way-

```
& C:\windows\System32\bitsadmin.exe /Util /SetIEProxy LocalSystem Manual_proxy http://<proxyserver>:<proxy port> "<Any bypasses to be added>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyEnable" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f

Reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v "ProxyServer" /t REG_SZ /d "http://procycorp.bac:80" /f

Comment: Does that actually work now? 7 years ago when I last tried this, it just changed the values in the registry, but you had to change Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings to actually get Windows to use the procy server.

Comment: This sets the current user (CU in HKCU), so not the local system user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [ProxyCFG.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384069(VS.85).aspx), which sets the proxy for any WinHTTP calls.

Comment: What versions of Windows have ProxyCFG.EXE? It's not in Windows 7, for example. Also, does IE use WinHTTP?

Comment: In Windows 7/Win 2008 R2 NetSH.exe is used for all proxy config stuff: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731131(WS.10).aspx